# why does ReferenceEquals(s1,s2) returns true

Tags: c#, string

```
  String s1 = "Hello";
  String s2 = "Hello";
```

Here s1, s2 are different but then why ReferenceEquals() is returning true

Comment: Why do you write that they are different?

Comment: @Lucero-  int c = 5;
            int b = 5;
            Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(b,c));
returns false, it differs in case of string only

Comment: in the case of `int`, that statement involves *boxing*, since `ReferenceEquals` accepts `(object,object)` - which is a **very** different scenario; `string` is a reference-types, so doesn't require boxing.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: IMO, that is a much more interesting question. Is it *guaranteed* by the specification to return false? Any thoughts on whether a future(?) CLR might start using "boxed integer caches" like Java for small integral values?

Comment: @Ani - an interesting question; I wouldn't *expect* so, but it perhaps *could* - especially for the 10 `ldc_i4_*` literal integer values with specific opcodes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is due to *interning* - the CLI automatically re-uses strings obtained **as literals** (i.e. strings that have come directly from your source code). Note that if you did:

```
char[] chars = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
string s1 = new string(chars);
string s2 = new string(chars);
```

they would **not** be the same string instance, as they have not come from literals.

This is documented against the [`Ldstr` IL instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr.aspx):

> The Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) guarantees that the result of two ldstr instructions referring to two metadata tokens that have the same sequence of characters return precisely the same string object (a process known as "string interning").

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, once it created in the memory following same String objects are refered to the previously created String object
for more
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Comment: Well, it is a bit more restrictive than that; interning (at least, automatic interning) only applies to *literals*.

Answer (score 2):

String is `immutable` so uses same reference for same value
Also see [Eric Lippert's blog](https://ericlippert.com/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/) for all about this.

Answer (score 1):

if you google "ReferenceEquals string"

you'll get [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a2feacfd-ca23-42ff-99ca-00d524e354ad)

The following was the accepted answer from the link, in case link dies

> In this example "obj1" and "obj2" are separate instances, Right ?

No - strings are reference-types, and obj1 and obj2 are two variables pointing to the same instance, due in-part to something called interning; basically, any string literal in an assembly* can share the same string reference. This is possible only because strings are immutable. You can also check for interned strings (string.IsInterned), and manually intern if you want (string.Intern).

> When two strings have same value, are they sharing same instance ?

They *might* have the same instance; but it isn't guaranteed. Strings that have been generated on-the-fly won't normally be interned; for example, the only ones that share references here are 2 & 4:

string tmp1 = "aa", tmp2 = "aaa";

string s1 = new string('a', 5),

s2 = "aaaaa",

s3 = tmp1 + tmp2,

s4 = "aaaaa";

Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(s1, s2));

Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(s1, s3));

Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(s1, s4));

Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(s2, s3));

Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(s2, s4));

Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(s3, s4));

*=strictly: net-module

Comment: Wow; that takes me back a few years :)

Comment: well that's interesting, kind of a "small world":)

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `String.Copy(String str)` static method to create strings that will be different objects

```
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = string.Copy("Hello");
```

then s1 and s2 will be referencing different objects.