# What is the difference Between Assignment and Creating Instance of String in C#?

Tags: c#, string, heap-memory

I have sample code.

```
var charMass = new char[] { 's', 't', 'r' };
string myString = new string(charMass);
string myString2 = new string(charMass);
string myString3 = "str";
string myString4 = "str";

bool bb1 = Object.ReferenceEquals(myString, myString2);
bool bb2 = Object.ReferenceEquals(myString, myString3);
bool bb3 = Object.ReferenceEquals(myString3, myString4);
```

Why bb1 and bb2 are false? I know that equals must show true, because it compares values, but what about memory allocation for those strings? Why myString3 and myString4 are pointing to the same block of memory in the heap but myString and myString2 not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232789/why-does-referenceequalss1-s2-returns-true

Probably the above link helps you.

Comment: This [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) can explain your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# compiler optimizes it so the same literals point to the same string instance

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned.aspx):

> The intern pool conserves string storage. **If you assign a literal
>   string constant to several variables, each variable is set to
>   reference the same constant** in the intern pool instead of
>   referencing several different instances of String that have identical
>   values.

Comment: I thought that myString and myString2 must be interned too and refer to the same intern object. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Intern pool is some kind of Hashtable,key is a string value, value is a reference to string in the heap, right?

Answer (score 4):

I answer your question here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty.aspx.

The short answer is: interning literal strings is *cheap and easy* and therefore is done by default. Interning dynamically-allocated strings *typically saves a small number of bytes at the cost of a huge amount of time* and is therefore *not worth bothering about*.  If you want to force interning, you can do so yourself.

Comment: What about internal hashtable for interned strings that contains string value as key, and reference to string in the heap? Richter told about this in his book, is this some kind of untouchable storage in the heap that lives until app domain will be unloaded? It is still not clear to me.

Comment: @IgorLozovsky: I don't understand the question you're asking here. Are you asking how String.Intern is implemented?

Comment: The CLR maintains a hashtable of strings on a per-process basis. They're shared across all app domains in that process. This info I found out in Jeffrey Richter's book.

Answer (score 1):

`myString` and `myString2` can never be reference-equal to each other (or to any other string) because you explicitly called the string constructor, resulting in a new object being created each time. Obviously this new object will not be reference-equal to any other already-existing object.

`myString3` and `myString4` are reference-equal because the compiler [interns the strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx): string values initialized with string literals at compile time end up being references to the same object at runtime:

> The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a
>   table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to
>   each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in
>   your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a
>   particular value only exists once in the system.
>
> For example, if you assign the same literal string to several
>   variables, the runtime retrieves the same reference to the literal
>   string from the intern pool and assigns it to each variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the compiler somehow optimises the `"str"` into a single *literal*, which it then assigns to each variable, which of course, strings being pointers, mean they both point to the same address.

Comment: The compiler does not optimize away the *variables*. It optimizes away the *literals*; two identical literals are generated to both point to the same location in the metadata string table.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the underlying implementation of String in the framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx

The way I see it is that for myString and myString2, you created those using char[] and there is not default lookup in Intern pool as string is being created.

In case of myString3 and myString4,
myString3 added value to InternPool and for myString4, you just got a reference as it was the sample block.

I was previously under the impression that in earlier version of framework IsIntern was optional and let to developer. Looks like that isn't necessarily the case