# Comparing 2 reference strings returns true

Tags: c#

```
string a = "abc";
string b = "abc";
Console.WriteLine(String.ReferenceEquals(a, b));
```

`a` and `b` are CLEARLY different references, yet, I get true. Why is this? Somewhere I've read that when you assign `abc` to `b`, the compiler sees that there's already the exact `abc` value in the heap and points to the same memory address as `a`, but if this was the case, then by that logic the last line of this code below should print `true`:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public int _num;
    public SomeClass(int num)
    {
        _num = num;
    }
}
var a = new SomeClass(3);
var b = new SomeClass(3);
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)); // prints false
```

Comment: Instances of `string` are interned. Instances of `SomeClass` are not.

Comment: Have you see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112610/referenceequals-working-wrong-with-strings) &/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232789/why-does-referenceequalss1-s2-returns-true) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `a` and `b` are CLEARLY different references.

No, they are not. That string is interned.

The 'catch' with strings in general is that `==` calls the `string.Equals` method, which does not only compare references, but [also the actual representation of the string](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,594).

Proof:

```
string a = "a";
string b = "a"; // intering
string c = new string(a.ToCharArray()); // no interning

bool r;

r = a == b; // true: references the same
r = a == c; // true: references different, match string value

r = (object)a == (object)b; // true: references the same

r = (object)a == (object)c; // false: references different
```

Comment: Nice explanation, with your comment `// true: references the same` you don't mean that line compares references right?

Comment: It does. String comparison is first on reference, than on string comparison. `a` and `b` share the same reference since the string is interned.

Comment: Oh didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

In the compilation step, string literals are pooled and all references to a specific value will be equal.

From the [specifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) (boldface mine):

> Each string literal **does not necessarily result in a new string instance**. When two or more string literals that are equivalent according to the string equality operator (Section 7.9.7) appear in the same assembly, these string literals **refer to the same string instance**.